# Facebook application callback url

Tags: java, facebook

I want to build facebook application and I am trying to do it using Java and so for that I searched over google and found some link:

- [Rebirth of T-rex](http://trexlim.blogspot.com/2008/03/my-first-sample-java-application-on.html)
- [T=Machine - 1](http://t-machine.org/index.php/2007/08/02/how-to-make-facebook-apps-using-java-part-1/)
- [T=Machine - 2](http://t-machine.org/index.php/2007/08/13/how-to-make-facebook-apps-using-java-part-2/)
- [The Screencast Blog](http://www.thescreencast.com/2007/06/getting-started-with-facebook-platform.html)

Most of these pages and blogs are old and have a description of callback url settings for the application. As I registered user of facebook I got the App ID and the App Secret and also gave a name to my application, but I didn't find any place to write or define the callback url for the application. There are **Site URL & Domain** settings under **Web**.

Is the **Site URL** same as the **Callback URL** defined in those websites and what is **Site Domain** for the application.

As these sites are pretty much old, of the year 2007-2008 are there any recent blogs out there and any other websites from where I can get information?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many changes in the application page recently.
Go to Appname->Edit->Web->site url to add callback url

Comment: thank you very much. As the site URL is localhost, so do I need **Domain** name?

Comment: if it is localhost you can access it only from your localmachine, this will do for testing purpose, but when you are ready to deploy,you need a domain name